# jQuery insertBefore/After() with multiple instances

Tags: jquery, insertafter

So i have this problem. I want to change order of list structure in specified moment.

The problem that it inserts all the elements.

How to specify the selector, so i got only the rearrangement in whole list order and get no copies from another list?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".row ul li:nth-child(2)").insertAfter(".row ul li:nth-child(3)");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <ul>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>12</li>
        <li>13</li>
        <li>14</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop over each `ul`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.row').each(function () {
        $(this).find('ul li:nth-child(2)').insertAfter($(this).find('ul li:nth-child(3)'));
    });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pvx8d3uc/1/